# unable to create, migrate model, register the model to admin and restart django server programmatically

Tags: django, django-models, reload, django-migrations

I am trying to create dynamic models and trying to migrate it programmatically and registering a model to the admin site. I could not hack into migration api but was able to run the manage (makemigrations and migrate command). I am able to do it. But when I register the model in the admin, it shows grayed out and I have to restart the server to get it enabled. I have not been able to restart server programmatically. I am using django 3.0.3. Any help here?

```
model = type(m.get("name"), (models.Model,), m.get("attrs"))
```

I am programmatically enabling the models in models list here

```
def migrate():
    from django.core import management
    from django.db.migrations.recorder import MigrationRecorder

    db_name = "programaticfetchfromdatabase"
    app_label = "programaticfetchfromdatabase"
    try:
        management.call_command("startapp", app_label)
        management.call_command("makemigrations", app_label)
        management.call_command("migrate", app_label, MigrationRecorder.Migration.objects.filter(
                app=app_label).last().__dict__.get("name"), "--database=="+db_name)

        return True
    except:
        # raise Exception("Unable to perform migration)
        return False

if migrate():
    from django.contrib import admin
    # If register and dont restart the model is grayed out
    admin.site.register(model)
   
    # so restarting server here
    # restart server (WHICH API do I use here)
    
    from django.utils import autoreload
    autoreload.restart_with_reloader()

    # I get port already in use error
```

I want to know why the model is grayed out after dynamic admin registration or I want to reload the django server programmatically

Answer (score 1):

It is

```
"--databe="+db_name
```

not

```
"--database=="+db_name
```

It is

```
try:
    ...
except:
    ...
```

not

```
try:
    ...
catch:
    ...
```

And the most important part, you do not want to use the django runserver to run your server on production websites.

Maybe look at django-mutant for inspiration on what you are trying to do, but I still wouldn't suggest dynamic models.

Comment: Thank you update to except. I use other languages and above is not exact code. apologies. w.r.t django-mutant I did start off with that and will look at it again. I just had a look at the project github and seems almost the same this except that it is being done in diffferent way. let me check this though. To keep me going on this issue which api helps reload server correctly and second any idea what api keeps track of model registration to admin so i dont have to restart server? Any help?

Comment: @user:8291840  - Thank you for this - "you do not want to use the django runserver to run your server on production". I am now sequentially reloading workers one by one using a HUP signal for Gunicorn/Uvicorn. This solves my problem partly indirectly.

Comment: A quick question. what api do i touch to get makemigrations (fake) run/create migrations for a model programmatically created like this - `model = type(m.get("name"), (models.Model,), m.get("attrs"))`. Makemigrations (fake makemigrations) dont migrate programmatically created models. Any help?

Comment: Have you worked on this Django API before? Any resources or help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64320562/unable-to-create-migrate-model-register-the-model-to-admin-and-restart-django

Comment: Unfortunately not, sorry.